# Loop through a new json object every X seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to make a timer or interval. So that a new data is being shown on the screen every X seconds. I currently have an array of objects, and I want to show one object at the time, and data refreshing every X seconds.

this is my json:

```
{
    "exampleData": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "fun film",
            "genre": "comedy"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "not so fun film",
            "genre": "horror"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is my little map function:

```
 const renderExample= data.exampleData.map(function (data, idx) {
      return (
         <h2 key={idx}>
            {data.title}
            {data.genre}
         </h2>
      )
   });
```

So when the component is rendered I want the first object to be shown: **title: fun film and genre comedy** then after X seconds I would like the other object to be shown **not so fun film, genre horror**

I was thinking about using a useEffect with a setTimout but I'm not too sure where to start. Any tips?

Comment: Consider starting by trying to implement your initial idea?

Comment: Your approach is reasonable. Tip: Use `useState` to store the current index of the element. You can use the length of the array and the modulo operator to update the state periodically in `useEffect`. You should first try on your own.

Comment: @trixn yes please if possible. I'm struggling with the useEffect. I have created a [index, setIndex] state and go the length of the array. However, I still have all items rendering at one time.

Comment: Perhaps read [this tutorial](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/build-a-react-timer-component-using-hooks) and then let us know if you're still stuck.  Actually I find great tutorials all over the place when I search the web, so where are you really stuck?  "not too sure where to start" is really vague.  Try to distill this down to a more specific problem.

Comment: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-knuth-o8sso?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thanks all. I did it, but I'm still going to go ahead and complete that tutorial! Cheers all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just increase the index every X seconds and use the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to keep it looping. (Untested example below.)

```
const Your_Component = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrent((current) => (current + 1) % data.length);
    }, 5000) // 5 seconds

    return () => clearInterval(intervalID);
  }, []);

  return (
    <h2>
      {data[current].title}
      {data[current].genre}
    </h2>
  )
}
```

Comment: Because of the closure of `setInterval` over the `current`, your code will only change `current` from 0 to 1 because you have omitted the dependencies of the `useEffect` hook. Adding the dependencies (`useEffect(() => {...}, [current, data.length]);`) will solve the problem but then `useEffect` will unnecessarily execute more than once. You could declare the `current` outside the component. This way `useEffect` won't depend on the `current` and it will only execute once.

Comment: @Yousaf I see what you mean, good tip. If i understand this right this could be easily fixed by passing a function to the `setCurrent` instead of the new index. See edited snippet

Comment: Yes the updated code will work. Although it doesn't matters in this case but you still have omitted `data.length` from the dependency array.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it. Same general concept as others, with a working example.

The main difference is that this uses the function form of `setActive` which prevents closures from being an issue in this case.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const data = {
  exampleData: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'fun film',
      genre: 'comedy',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'not so fun film',
      genre: 'horror',
    },
  ],
};
function Example() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    // create an interval
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      // increment and modulo the active state so it never goes out of bounds.
      // Set the new active using the function form of setActive so the closure doesn't matter
      setActive((active) => (active + 1) % data.exampleData.length);
    }, 1000);
    // Clean up the effect
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);
  const currentData = data.exampleData[active];

  return (
    <h2>
      {currentData.title}
      {currentData.genre}
    </h2>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```